# Rebus with SQS - a failed message is handled by 2 consumers more times than number of configured re-tries

Tags: amazon-sqs, rebus

I have a failing message in Rebus with SQS transport. I have 2 Rebus consumers, each configured with 5 re-tries, and I can see that a failed message is handled from 5 times up to 10 times. I thought it's a bug first, but later realized it's probably an expected behaviour. My understanding is that when a message fails for the first time in Rebus consumer 1, it's made visible in the queue again, and potentially received by Rebus consumer 2. Each consumer counting number of re-tries independently, thus handling it up to 10 times in total. Am I correct in my understanding that it's a correct and expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Rebus tracks the caught exceptions in memory, so you are absolutely correct

I've found no better way of tracking exceptions between delivery attempts.